# Avoid creating duplicate class instances

Tags: python, performance

I am working with a very large dataset, and am looping over chunks of data to add elements to a class. There are many duplicated values in my data, meaning that I am creating a class instance for the same data many times. From some of the testing I've done, it seems that actually creating the instance of the class is the most expensive part of the operation so I want to minimise this as much as possible.

My question is:
**What is the least expensive (time) way of avoiding creating duplicate class instances? Ideally I would like to create a class instance once only and all duplicates reference the same instance**. I can't remove duplicates from my data at the outset, but I want to make sure I minimise any costly procedures.

Here is a toy example that I hope illustrates my problem. The commented out section shows my thinking for how I might be able to shave off time.

In this example `Person` contains 2 methods that call `sleep` to demonstrate a time cost to creating an instance. In my example, the code will run in 4.22 seconds (`(SLEEP_1 * 6) + (SLEEP_2 * 6)`). Seeing as I have a person "James" present 3 times, I am looking to find a way to add this person only once, and then reference this for the 2 duplicates.

I would then expect the code to run in ~2.8s (`(SLEEP_1 * 4) + (SLEEP_2 * 4)`)

```
import time
from collections import defaultdict

SLEEP_1 = 0.2
SLEEP_2 = 0.5

# A class `Person` has a load of methods, 
# meaning that creating an instance has a non-negligible time-cost over millions of calls. 
class Person:
    def __init__(self, info):
        self._id = info['_id']
        self.name = info['name']
        self.nationality = info['nationality']
        self.age = info['age']
        self.can_drink_in_USA = self.some_long_fun()
        self.can_fly_solo = self.another_costly_fun()

    def some_long_fun(self):
        time.sleep(SLEEP_1)
        if self.age >= 21:
            return True
        return False

    def another_costly_fun(self):
        time.sleep(SLEEP_2)
        if self.age >= 18:
            return True
        return False


# Some data to iterate over
# Note that "James" is present 3 times
teams = {
    "team1": [
        {"_id": "foo", "name": "James", "nationality": "French", "age": 32},
        {"_id": "bar", "name": "Frank", "nationality": "American", "age": 36},
        {"_id": "foo", "name": "James", "nationality": "French", "age": 32}
    ],
    "team2": [
        {"_id": "foo", "name": "James", "nationality": "French", "age": 32},
        {"_id": "baz", "name": "Oliver", "nationality": "British", "age": 26},
        {"_id": "qux", "name": "Josh", "nationality": "British", "age": 42}
    ]
}


seen = defaultdict(int)
team_directory = defaultdict(list)

start_time = time.time()
for team in teams:
    for i, person in enumerate(teams[team]):
        if person['_id'] in seen:
            print(f"{person['name']} [_id: {person['_id']}] already exists in Person class")
            # p = getattr(Person, '_id') == person['_id']
            # team_directory[team].append(p)
            # continue
        print(f"Person {i + 1} = {person['name']}")
        p = Person(info=person)
        team_directory[team].append(p)
        seen[person['_id']] += 1

finish_time = time.time() - start_time
expected_finish = round((SLEEP_1 * 6) + (SLEEP_2 * 6), 2)
print(f"Built a teams directory in {round(finish_time, 2)}s [expect: {expected_finish}s]")

# Loop over the results to check - I want each team to have 3 people
# (so I can't squash duplicates from the outset

for t in team_directory:
    roster = " ".join([p.name for p in team_directory[t]])
    print(f"Team {team} contains these people: {roster}")
```

Comment: Store a minimum of identifying data (here the "_id") in an immutable data structure (tuple or just string) and put it in a set after creating the object and check if it is already there before creating the object. If it is too large for a set in memory, use a database like e. g. Sqlite.

Comment: That's more or less what I'm doing with `if person['_id'] in seen:`

Comment: What is the problem with this solution?

Comment: Because if `person['_id'] in seen` I need to reference the instance where `Person._id == person['_id']` and I'm not sure how to do this efficiently / at all. Ultimately, I need to add this: `team_directory[team].append(p)`

Comment: Instead of a set "seen" how about a dict where keys are the "person['_id']" and values are the created Person objects? It wouldn't need much more memory and would be as efficient for testing for key presence and for accessing the value for given key.

Comment: If your dataset can fit in a python dict, or rather RAM of one machine, it's not "bigdata". As suggested, a database might suit your needs better than a dict, and they can already enforce equality/unique constraints. If you want to compare equality of Python classes, maybe don't rely on just an ID, and implement `__eq__`

Comment: @MichaelButscher - I guess the thing I'm not clear on is how to reference an object instead of creating a new instance. For example to commented out section (`p = getattr(Person, '_id') == person['_id']`) doesn't work "`AttributeError: type object 'Person' has no attribute '_id'`"

Comment: @OneCricketeer - OK not big data. I have hundreds of millions of elements in a list, so I need to perform hundreds of millions of operations. Would using a database be quicker than adding to a dict / class?

Comment: Depends on the database, but in general, no, since I doubt your dataset will fit uncompressed in RAM. But it would certainly be faster to get your answer using `GROUP BY team` sql query

Comment: @OneCricketeer ok thanks. Any chance you could expand on the use of `__eq__` - I'm not sure how this would address my problem seeing as I would have to create two instances to then compare them (non?)

Comment: My comment was mostly related to the fact that it's unclear how you're guaranteeing you didn't mistype an ID field. If you're trying to prevent two people named James with the exact same age, nationality, etc from being on a team, you'll want to compare equality of all fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seen` can be used as cache to associate the person `_id` with an already created `Person` object.

This can look like (code up to and including the main for-loop, remaining code doesn't need a change):

```
seen = {}
team_directory = defaultdict(list)

start_time = time.time()
for team in teams:
    for i, person in enumerate(teams[team]):
        if person['_id'] in seen:
            print(f"{person['name']} [_id: {person['_id']}] already exists in Person class")
            p = seen[person['_id']]
            team_directory[team].append(p)
            continue
        print(f"Person {i + 1} = {person['name']}")
        p = Person(info=person)
        team_directory[team].append(p)
        seen[person['_id']] = p
```

An assignment like e. g. `seen[person['_id']] = p` only copies a reference to an object but not the object itself, therefore it doesn't need much memory.

Answer (score 0):

> creating an instance has a non-negligible time-cost over millions of calls

Then don't call them. Your two examples are *derived functions*; they use other attributes, and therefore can remain instance methods, which need not be stored in instance fields themselves. Plus, you never use them in the code outside of the constructor, so they can be removed from there and deferred to whatever code actually needs them.

Also, you only need one function for that example code, and no sleeps

```
def age_check(age):
    def f(over):
        return age >= over
    return f

age_check(self.age)(18)
age_check(self.age)(21)
```

Or, simpler

```
def age_check(self, over):
    return self.age >= over
```

> need to reference the instance where `Person._id == person['_id']` and I'm not sure how to do this efficiently / at all. Ultimately, I need to add this: `team_directory[team].append(p)`

Don't use a list and append. Use a dict that maps the `Person._id` to the person instance itself. Then you don't need to waste cycles iterating over the list to see if a person exists already

Obviously, this all assumes your dataset will fit in memory

Comment: The sleep in the function is just to demonstrate a time cost to creating an instance. In my example, the code will run in 4.22 seconds (`(SLEEP_1 * 6) + (SLEEP_2 * 6)`). Seeing as I have a `person` present 3 times, I am looking to find a way to only add this person once, and then reference this for the 2 duplicates. I would then expect the code to run in ~2.8s (`(SLEEP_1 * 4) + (SLEEP_2 * 4)`)

Comment: Sure, but like I said, those functions don't appear to need to be called to simply parse your original data into the class. Simply extracting id fields requires no sleep calls

Comment: OK that's a useful idea - thanks. I'm not clear on how `they can be removed from there and deferred to whatever code actually needs them` will help. I'll need to call these methods at some point, so doesn't this just kick the can down the road?

Comment: Sure, but it should be "quicker" because you are filtering out the duplicates ahead of time